# Are both $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ are topologies on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let  $\tau_{1}=\{G \subseteq \mathbb{R} : G \ \text {is  finite  or}\  \mathbb{R} \setminus G \text{ is finite} \}$ and $\tau_{2}=\{G \subseteq \mathbb{R} : G \ \text {is countable  or}\  \mathbb{R} \setminus G \text{ is countable } \}$.

Are $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ both topologies on $\Bbb R$?

I think yes they both are, since $\tau_1$  is  cofinite topology and $\tau_2$  is  co-countable topology.

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the 2 (or 3) conditions that make a set of subsets a topology? Just verify them

Comment: An important issue here: does "countable" imply infinite in your usage?

Comment: @Berci   pliz  give me  any hints ??

Comment: $\tau_1$ is not the cofinite topology because $\{1\}$ is a finite (therefore open) set but the complement is not finite, so it's not the cofinite topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axioms for a set $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ to form a topology are:

1. $\emptyset, X\in\tau$
2. $A, B\in\tau\implies A\cap B\in\tau$
3. For any index set $I$, if $A_i\in\tau$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\in\tau$.

Now, 1. and 2. clearly hold for both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, but 3. *fails* for both.